# How do you properly modify the state and fetch calls in a react component in a test?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing

I'm pretty new to React and JS testing in general. I have a React Component that makes a request on its componentDidMount method that prefetches things and then once it's fetched it will supply that information to construct the HTML in the render method. How do I go about making sure that this componentDidMount call is a mocked call while also ensuring that I set the state isLoaded?

This is what I have so far.

```
beforeEach(() => {
    container = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(container);
});

afterEach(() => {
    document.body.removeChild(container);
    container = null;
});
it("can render UserSelector", () => {
    act(() => {
        ReactDOM.render(<UserSelector/>, container);
    })
    const select = container.querySelector("select");
    expect(select.value).toBe(""); // ignore this expect, just testing atm
})
```

where the UserSelector component looks like so

```
class UserSelector extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error: null,
            isLoaded: false,
            selected: this.props.assigned,
            items: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(`${API_ROOT}users?page=0`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        items: result["results"]
                    });
                },
                (error) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        error
                    });
                }
            )
    }

    render() {
        const dropDownSelection = []
        const {error, isLoaded, items} = this.state;
        for (const [index, value] of items.entries()) {
            dropDownSelection.push(<option user_id={value["id"]}
                                           value={value["username"]}
                                           selected={this.state.selected?.username == value["username"]}
            >{value["username"]}</option>)
        }


        if (!isLoaded) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>;
        } else {
            return (
                <Form.Group>
                    <Form.Control as="select" name="user" onChange={this.props.onChange}>
                        <option>User</option>
                        {dropDownSelection}
                    </Form.Control>
                </Form.Group>
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What testing framework are you using?

Comment: @slideshowp2 I'm using react-testing-library, should I be using something else?